# Extracting Disqus comments, reputation and likes from webpages using python?

Tags: python, comments, disqus

I am trying to figure out a way to extract comments, the author's reputation and likes using python. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty generic question.

However, [Discus has an API](http://disqus.com/api/docs/) and a [python library](https://github.com/disqus/disqus-python), which you can use to request comments for an application you own. You can get yourself an API key and use the wonderful `requests` python library to make requests of data.

If you're trying to scrape them from another site, well, i'm not sure if the API does this. If not, consider using `scrapy` to build a bot and scrape results.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about what exactly you're trying to do, look into web-scraping libraries such as: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/